# How to print or save the online edited image (with javascript/jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I made an simple image manipulation experiment with html, css and javascript/jquery.

We can upload an image from local drive and displayed in browser.
After that we can also edit/tag the displayed image.
I use [this](https://github.com/idelahoz/Jquery-Image-Tag) jquery image tag plugin.

Then I think about, how can i save/print the edited image?

This is my code snippet :

```
$(function () {
    $(":file").change(function () {
        if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        }
    });
});

function imageIsLoaded(e) {
    $('#myImg').attr('src', e.target.result);
    $('#myImg').imageTag();
};
```

Here's the real live app : http://nanonimos.com/upload-tag-image/

and [this is the source code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9j7l9gxy6p7a3zd/finalupload.zip?dl=1).

Any clue/advice would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: That app doesn't even edit the image. All it does is just create a `div` and overlap the image.

Comment: it may be possible to manually write the headers yourself for a filedownload and then append the base64 image data. set the resultant string as the href of a link with target blank and then trigger the click event on it. it might work since browsers will allow you to pass entire documents in the url bar, if this doesn't work, you may look at temporarily storing it on the server and then triggering the new tab for the file download.

Comment: Hi Choz. Ya, i think so. But i guess is it posibble to create similar app that can upload image from our local computer, edit it online, and then save/print it as edited image?

Comment: @Harkedian Yes, it's possible. Even with your current tagging sample should work if you record the position where the tags are, and process it on the server to recreate the graphic from the current image and overlap it with those tags. Please check this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1827/Web-Graphics-On-The-Fly-in-ASP-NET, it uses asp.net to create graphics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the whole div to an canvas then convert the canvas into data uri(png,jpeg).
Check this [Fiddle`canvastoimage`](http://jsfiddle.net/8ypxW/3/) for more.

Comment: Hi @Vendhan. want to ask a little bit more. How to make it automatically save/download image when we press 'save as image' button?. Here's the link : http://nanonimos.com/pin-save-image/ and here's the source : https://www.dropbox.com/s/qbs2o6fk88qzyxm/FINAL1.0.zip?dl=1

Comment: Hi Harkedian, So far you just convert the HTML div element to a canvas using html2pdf JS lib., For convert the Canvas to data uri(png, jpeg), you have to use [Canvas2image](https://github.com/hongru/canvas2image)  JS lib.

Answer (score 1):

Use this function(From Stackoverflow) to convert dataURI to blob:

```
function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
    // convert base64/URLEncoded data component to raw binary data held in a string
    var byteString;
    if (dataURI.split(',')[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0)
        byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    else
        byteString = unescape(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

    // separate out the mime component
    var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];

    // write the bytes of the string to a typed array
    var ia = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    return new Blob([ia], {type:mimeString});
}
```

and then whenever you want to save just post this file  to server.

In HTML5 you can do like this:

```
var blob = dataURItoBlob(data);
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("imageFile", blob);
```

Then send it with ajax like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url:"url to file",
  data: fd,
  success: function(result){
  //check success
  };
});
```